# module 'pandas' has no attribute 'sparsedtype' - Catboost classifier

Tags: pandas, catboost

I am working on catboost classifier algorithm and while doing model fit - I am getting this error -module 'pandas' has no attribute 'sparsedtype'. Any suggestion pls.

I am using Pandas version - 0.23.4

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

SparseDtype was introduced in version 0.24.0 of pandas.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.SparseDtype.html

Install more recent version.

Comment: Sure. Upgraded Python Version has resolved the issue. Thanks.